# IB API, placeOrder works from Python but not from VB. What is wrong in my VB-code?

Tags: python, vb.net, interactive-brokers

I experience problems with placing an order using VB and IB API.

Using Python I can get historical data and place orders using any of the following contracts. I tried ib_insync and IB-native API as well.

With ib_insync the order gets filled immediatelly.

```
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=0)

# Callback if order is filled 
def order_status(trade):
    if trade.orderStatus.status == 'Filled':
        fill = trade.fills[-1]
        print(f'{fill.time} - {fill.execution.side} {fill.contract.symbol} {fill.execution.shares} @ {fill.execution.avgPrice}')

# Contract = Option(symbol= "EOE",  exchange= "FTA", currency= "EUR", multiplier= 100, lastTradeDateOrContractMonth= "20230818", strike= 775, right= "P")
# Contract = Stock(symbol=  "ASML", exchange= "AEB", currency= "EUR"
# Contract = Index(symbol=  "EOE",  exchange= "FTA", Currency= "EUR")

Contract = Future(symbol= "EOE",  exchange= "FTA", Currency= "EUR", multiplier= 200, lastTradeDateOrContractMonth= "202308")

ib.qualifyContracts(contract)   # Inspect fields filled by IB

bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(contract, endDateTime='', durationStr='1 D', barSizeSetting='1 min', whatToShow='trades', useRTH=True)  


#Create order object
order = Order()
order.action = 'BUY'
order.totalQuantity = 1
order.orderType = 'MKT'

trade = ib.placeOrder(contract, order)
trade.filledEvent+= order_status        # Attach the callback function order_Status

ib.sleep(0.5)

trade.log
print("trade.orderStatus= " , trade.orderStatus.status)
```

But if I use VB I can't place an order and don't see that ewrapper.openOrder or ewrapper.orderStatus are called by the system.
I also don't know how to see if all fields of the contract are filled.

My code for VB (apart from connecting to IB [TWS is running and my program checks connection]) is

```
    Sub TestOrder()
        Dim orderIBKR As IBApi.Order = New IBApi.Order()
        orderIBKR.Action = 'BUY'
        orderIBKR.TotalQuantity = 1
        orderIBKR.OrderType = "MKT"

        Dim contractIBKR As IBApi.Contract = New IBApi.Contract()
        contractIBKR.Symbol = "EOE"
        contractIBKR.Currency = "EUR"
        contractIBKR.Exchange = "FTA"
        contractIBKR.Multiplier = 200
        contractIBKR.SecType = "FUT"
        contractIBKR.LastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "202308"

        ibClient.reqContractDetails(idOrderIBKR, contractIBKR)
        idOrderIBKR += 1                        '// Has been defined while connecting to IB

        ibClient.placeOrder(idOrderIBKR, contractIBKR, orderIBKR)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    End Sub

    Public Event orderStatusEvent As EventHandler(Of OrderStatusEventArgs)
    
    Public Sub orderStatus(orderId As Integer, status As String, filled As Decimal, remaining As Decimal, avgFillPrice As Double, permId As Integer, parentId As Integer, lastFillPrice As Double, clientId As Integer, whyHeld As String, mktCapPrice As Double) Implements EWrapper.orderStatus
    
        Helpers.logger.Debug("EWrapper.orderStatus (Enter)  orderId= " & orderId)
        RaiseEvent orderStatusEvent(Me, New OrderStatusEventArgs(orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFillPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId, whyHeld, mktCapPrice))

        MsgBox("OrderStatus. Id: " & orderId & ", Status: " & status & ", Filled: " & Util.DecimalMaxString(filled) & ", Remaining: " & Util.DecimalMaxString(remaining) &
        ", AvgFillPrice: " & Util.DoubleMaxString(avgFillPrice) & ", PermId: " & Util.IntMaxString(permId) & ", ParentId: " & Util.IntMaxString(parentId) &
        ", LastFillPrice: " & Util.DoubleMaxString(lastFillPrice) & ", ClientId: " & Util.IntMaxString(clientId) & ", WhyHeld: " & whyHeld & ", mktCapPrice: " & Util.DoubleMaxString(mktCapPrice))
        RaiseEvent MyEvent(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        Helpers.logger.Debug("EWrapper.orderStatus (Exit)  orderId= " & orderId)
    End Sub
```

No order gets placed using VB and I do not receive any callbacks form IB.

Any idea why placeOrder doesn't work.
Is ib.qualifyContracts(contract) specific for ib_insync  (I couldn't find it using VB).
How can I check if placeOrder did the job?